# Where is the file that generates the config.rb file?

Tags: ruby, sass

When I create a new Compass project, it generates several directories and files and provides the config.rb file. Rather than changing the config file every time I start a project, can I set this up in a existing default file? and where is it?

Comment: Compass doesn't care how the config.rb file got there, it just cares that it exists and that your directory structure matches what's configured in the file.  If you would like to generate a config.rb without all of the other directories/files, try `compass create --bare`.

Comment: That helps. But rather than changing the config file on every project, how can I change what is automatically generated?

Comment: I don't think you can, at least not without modifying Compass itself.  Personally, I would set up a shell script to do what you're asking for.  Either copy your ideal file where you want it or to run the command for creating a new project with all of the necessary flags set (see the command generating tool here:  http://compass-style.org/install/)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this pull request, it might help: https://github.com/kahlil/grunt-compass/issues/13

Comment: Kind of a circuitous way to go about it. Is there not a file located in Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass that can be changed?

Comment: Yeah it seems that with out of the box Sass it cannot be achieved however this Grunt plugin has the option already merged into it (https://github.com/jcassee/grunt-compass) maybe grunt is something that adapts better to what you are needing?